# Display image from a datatable in asp:image in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, code-behind

I have a datatable which is filled from the resultset of a 1 row select statement (via a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008) and it contains a `Image` typed column which I store images in.

I have an `asp:image` control on an aspx page and i want to set the image to the corresponding field of that datatable but anything I do I can not.
Please tell me how can I set the `asp:image` to image column of that datatable **from the code behind**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Data URL scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="<%# ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(Eval("ColumnA")) %>" />

protected static string ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(object rawImg)
{
    string img = "data:image/gif;base64,{0}"; //change image type if need be
    byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = (byte[])rawImg;        
    string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
    return String.Format(img, returnValue);
}
```

Comment: Dear Rick, I was not able to map this solution to the context of problem I am dealing with. In the previous problem you helped me, there was an object data source I was binding to, but what if I have a datatable in code behind and this image is the only control I want to bind to?

Comment: How should I tell from code behind that img must be be bound to that datatable. It was the biggest problem I dealt with to apply your previous solution to this context.

Comment: I put an img tag inside a listview and use this method. The problem solved. Again thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could put `<img src="data:image/png;base64,<BASE64 STRING>" />`, so you would set the `asp:image`'s `ImageUrl` property to `"data:image/png;base64,xxx"`.

However, I suspect the browser support on this is spotty, works fine in IE9 and firefox, but I'm unsure of older browsers support for this.

An alternative I would recommend though, is to create a generic handler `ashx`, that reads the database and returns an image.  You can check out this website on how to do it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx, you would then set the `ImageUrl` property to this handlers address.

Comment: Dear Mathew, How should I configure img to accept from datatable from code behind then?

Answer (score 2):

[Display Images from SQL Server Database using ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx)

aspx file

```
<asp:image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ="ImageCSharp.aspx?ImageID=1"/>
```

cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
   {
        string strQuery = "select Name, ContentType, Data from tblFiles where id=@id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value
        = Convert.ToInt32 (Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
            + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Pranay, The solution was correct but It has side-effects on app design. However your solution is correctly working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by using Convert.ToBase64String

```
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr["YourImageField"];
        string b64img = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64img;
```