# Display varbinary as a downloadable link

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Fairly straightforward question, I have images stored in my database as varbinary and would like to provide a link to these images rather than displaying them on the website. When a user clicks the link he/she should be able to download the image.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What approaches did you consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image is served in response to a request.

```
<img src="?" /> <!-- what goes here? -->
```

You need to create an [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to receive requests for these images.

A handler is an executable available at a specific URL which can respond to your request; in this case, by serving the binary data of an image. An ASPX page is a valid handler, though there are more efficient handler types for images.

```
<img src="MyHandler.aspx?imageId=123" />
```

The handler should do a few things:

- validate that the ID is valid and that the caller has permissions (if needed)
- retrieve the image from the database
- set appropriate response headers
- use `Response.BinaryWrite()` to send the binar data to the client.

Note that if you are using ASP.Net MVC, you can use a controller as your handler.

An alternative method is to base 64 encode the bytes and embed them directly in the image tag.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

This is a useful technique for small images or when the expense of multiple requests is very high.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

More reading:

- [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)
- [Dynamic Image Generation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a page that takes an image-id and returns the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this question:

[Display image from a datatable in asp:image in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143323/display-image-from-a-datatable-in-aspimage-in-code-behind)

I had a similar problem an that answer solved my question. Beside that, you can use binaryimage component from Telerik:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/binaryimage.aspx