# show image from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to show binary data ( image) from database without using handler

```
   var imgLogo = cid.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Logo"].ToString();
```

could you please suggest me the way to do. here is my aspx content

how i can set imageUrl from codebehind? i have tried below one but its not working

```
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])cid.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Logo"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

how  i can set the imageUrl from this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: ***WHAT*** kind of database? MySQL? Oracle? DB2? SQL Server? Postgres? Something else???

Comment: Maybe you can check this for a moment:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/display-images-from-sql-server-database-in-asp.net-gridview-control.aspx

Comment: its sql server, @Krekkon -- i tried that but this example created with handler class.

Comment: And what is the problem with that? Your problem is, you cannot get the image or cannot set to the ImageController in xaml?

Answer (score 1):

Well the code you have only sets the image to be written to the response. 
you need to use the ASP.NET Image control, then use a Handler to serve up the image.

The handler would be the one to read the image bytes from the database, then read it into the Response like you have done somewhat.

take a look:

[Retrieve image from database into a image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731712/retrieve-image-from-database-into-a-image-tag)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but here in this example below handler is used.string.Format("/viewImage.ashx?memberreportid={0}&imageID={1}", Session["memberreportid"], "{0}");                                                                one more thing, i am also using  <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgLogo" > control now my question is how i can bind the url from codebehind without using handler ? or without handler its not possible. thanks

Comment: it is not possible without the handler. You could write to disk with a random filename but the problem is, it will be most likely a situation where the random file name could be overwritten in some way with something else AND it will hurt performance as it needs to write to disk then to load from disk. Best practice is to use the handler which will serve the image.

Comment: as per the provided example, Can i pass directly the bytes instead of querystring value to handler and then retrive the bytes. i mean i dont want to perform database call on that handler its simpley as passing the parameter to handler and return the image. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The handler NEEDS to know the parameters - and thats done by the querystring. Then from that, you call the DB which then gets the image served up to the requester (i.e the image) Also you wouldn't be passing the bytes TO the handler

Comment: ok, that means i have to write an db call in handler and i cant directly pass the bytes to handler to generate the image.