# how show image in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I save image in database then want to load and show image in image control.
I load data from database.control image is:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgShow" runat="server" />
```

code to show image:

```
imgShow=listUser[0].File;   // File is byte[]
```

listUser[0].File is byte[] .how can show image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve image from database into a image tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731712/retrieve-image-from-database-into-a-image-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Image</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("yourimagebytefield") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("yourimagebytefield")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="100" width="200"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i save image in byte to the database.listUser[0].File is not url of image.its image.

Comment: in my code "listUser[0].File" is byte data so pass your database field byte value there.

Comment: are you display image in single image control or gridview? and put your full code here so i explain in brief to you.

Comment: i want show all of them  in gridview ..i change code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already got your answer. I would just like to add that its never a good idea to store image directly in the database, its not an efficient method. What you should do instead is to store the image in a directory and then store the location of that image in the database.Its going to be much more efficient.

Comment: thanks for answer.image is secure and we cant save in directory sines customer dont like do it.